# The configuration for com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, spring, datasource, c3p0

I am looking for help with configuration of my data source type `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`

I need to have 1000 database connections available concurrently.

I started with following configuration and tried to increase the number for `initialPoolSize`, `maxPoolSize`, `minPoolSize` but it doesn’t work.

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="someUrl"/>
    <property name="user" value="someUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="somePass"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="300" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value=“3" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" /> 
    <property name="minPoolSize" value=“3" />
</bean>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? (`maxPoolSize` of 10 is probably way too small for 1000 concurrent users. but it sounds like "doesn't work" means something more for you then "doesn't perform well".)

Comment: Thank you so much Steve for your time and response. I tried with 100 and 200 for the maxPoolSize but not working. Do you have a working sample configuration for a big maxPoolSize?

Comment: no, there's no special config you need for a big pool size. what does "not working" mean? what actually happens?

Comment: (one thing: acquireIncrement = 1 is a bad idea. it means every client must experience the full latency of a Connection acquisition while the pool is expanding. another thing: in your config, you've overridden the default Connection acquistion behavior to perform more frequent but fewer retries. any particular reason?)

Comment: Thanks for your input. My config now is the following but getting this: 

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="someUrl"/>
    <property name="user" value="someUser"/>
    <property name="password" value="somePass"/>
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
</bean>

Comment: I use those: c3p0-0.9.5-pre6.jar and mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.3.jar

Comment: Your problem is with Connection acquisition. Your application is unable to connect to your database with the settings you've provided. The root cause Exception nested in the Exception you've shown will contain details of what went wrong. You'll need to look at that to debug, if you can't figure out what's wrong with your Connection settings (e.g. jdbcUrl, user, password) by inspection. If the Exceptions in your log are too truncated, if they don't show the root cause Exception, you'll have to figure out how to untruncate them in your logging lib.

Comment: Thanks Steve.
When I run my test with 12 concurrent calls everything works fine
When I run more than 12 calls, the first a few calls got connections, then the run stuck for getting new connections and the error happens.
It looks like something else is the cause.
How many concurrent calls can ComboPooledDataSource handle?

Comment: there's no hard limit on the number of concurrent Connections c3p0 pools can handle, although as things get big you have to tune for performance and eventually performance degrades. it certainly doesn't break at a hard limit of 12 Connections. 100-ish Connection pools are not uncommon. again, you want to look at the Exception that c3p0 is experiencing when trying to acquire (the 13th?) Connection. you might have a limit set @ mysql, tho 12 would be tiny. see eg http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html max_connections & open-files-limit. check the root cause Exception.

Comment: (when you do get things working, if really you want a 1000 simultaneous Connections, be sure to set a large number of helper threads, numHelperThreads as well as a large maxPoolSize. 1000 is a lot; in ordinary use cases, you can handle more users than you have Connections, as clients do other work besides interacting with the database. if you will have several thousand simultaneous clients, there will be some performance degradation due to Thread contention. if you have good, mullticore hardware to handle your load, consider setting up multiple pools rather than just one to reduce contention.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help.The number of MySql database connections was not the issue. There was some environment issue on my side. Due to the tight schedule I switched to BoneCP. Now everything works fine with 1000 concurrent calls with the default number of MySql connections. The performance looks very good. I appreciate all your time and help. And we may do developer's talk another time. Thank you again for your time and help. All the best.